# the paypal payment page price calculation

Tags: javascript, paypal

I want to create a price calculation for my Paypal payment option. I am using javascript to do it. But it doesn't work. So can anyone  help me? Below is the code:

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function dp(price) {
    string = "" + price;
    number = string.length - string.indexOf('.');
    if (string.indexOf('.') == -1) return string + '.00';
    if (number == 1) return string + '00';
    if (number == 2) return string + '0';
    if (number > 3) return string.substring(0, string.length - number + 3);
    return string;
}

function calculate() {
    document.calcform.total1.value = dp((document.calcform.amount.value) * (document.calcform.quantity1.value))

}
</script>


<p>number of licenses (US$59.99 per license):</p>
<p><form name="calcform" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="sample@paypal.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="MY">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="abc">
<input type="text" name="quantity1" size="50" ONCHANGE="calculate()">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" ONCHANGE="calculate()" value="59.99">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value = "J-2011">

</form></p>

enter to process payment
```

Answer (score 1):

add the hidden box with the name "total1" inside the form tag.

```
<input type="hidden" name="total1" value = "">
```

Comment: also add the calculate() function in form tag with the onsubmit attribute. <form name="calcform" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" onsubmit="calculate()"> and add a submit buton at the end of the form.